# How to view hundreds of local html files efficiently by safari web-browser and Python3

Tags: html, python-3.x, bokeh

I have used bokeh to generate 400 graphs and saved them into 400 html-files (`file_1.html` ... `file_400.html`)  on my local drive of my Mac.

An example of the codes that I used to generate a graph and save it is below

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, save

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

x = np.arange(1, 1000)  # all 400 graphs have the same x
y1 = np.arange(1, 1000)*2  # different file can have different y
p.line(x, y1, line_width=2)

output_file('file_1.html')
save(p)
```

I need to view the 400 html-files one by one, and I am interested only in a zoomed-in view of each graph, meaning the last 100 points of each graph. Note that the curve in each graph has to be viewed by me (due to my expertise), so I cannot use things like artificial intelligence to view the graphs for me.

What I can do now, is:

1. open the folder containing these 400 html-files
2. double click one file then it will be opened with safari web-browser
3. click the zoom-in button defined by `bokeh`
4. find the area of the last 100 points and drag a rectangle by mouse to zoom-in
5. close this file
6. repeat the above 5 steps for another 399 times.

This approach is very time-consuming and boring.

Do you have better ways to go through all these files?

One preferred feature is that I can open them all in a window, they are automatically zoomed-in, and I just need to hit the button of `left-arrow` and `right-arrow` on my keyboard to navigate through the graphs.

Looking forward to your help and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This actually seems like a perfect use case for a little Bokeh server application you can run locally. You can put the code in a file `app.py` then run `bokeh serve --show app.py` at the command line.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import Button, ColumnDataSource, TextInput
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, row
from bokeh.plotting import figure

current = 0

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 500)
y = np.sin(x)    
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot = figure(x_range=(10,20), title="Plot 0")
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source)

def update_data(i):
    global current
    current = i

    # compute new data or load from file, etc
    source.data = dict(x=x, y = np.sin(x*(i+1)))
    plot.title.text = "Plot %d" % i

def update_range(attr, old, new):
    plot.x_range.start = float(start.value)
    plot.x_range.end = float(end.value)

start = TextInput(title="start", value="10")
start.on_change('value', update_range)
end = TextInput(title="start", value="20")
end.on_change('value', update_range)

next = Button(label="next")
next.on_click(lambda: update_data(current+1))
prev = Button(label="prev")
prev.on_click(lambda: update_data(current-1))

curdoc().add_root(row(widgetbox(start, end, next, prev), plot))
```

This could be improved with some error handling and maybe some additional bells and whistles, but is hopefully demonstrative. It yields the interactive app below:

---

[image]

Comment: That was a lot more elegant solution.

Comment: There are definitely times when Selenium is a good tool (Bokeh uses it internally to generate PNG exports, e.g.)

Comment: @bigreddot thanks for your help. Seems nice, but in my case I also need to read the html-file and zoomed-in. In your codes, the graphs are just made in the memory, not saved in files.

Comment: You could certainly save the *data* in external files, and have an app read them in. It was not evident from your question having things in separate, already fully rendered HTML files, was a *requirement* as opposed to just how you happened to be doing things. If that's the case then the other answer with selenium is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, let's see how we can do this. My first thought is, this could be accomplished through selenium. I'm going to assume that you haven't used it before. In short, it's a way to programmatically do things with a browser.

Let's get started with that! Install the python library

```
pip install selenium
```

You'll also need to install geckodriver (we'll use firefox in this example). If you're on osx you can install that with brew.

```
brew install geckodriver
```

Then we can start writing our script to open 400 tabs! It'll open all the figures that you have locally. I'll leave it up to you how to figure out how to zoom. The documentation for selenium can be [found here ->](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

(the script uses python 3, and pathlib only exists in python 3)

```
from pathlib import Path
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

html_path = Path.cwd()
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

for no in range(1, 400):
    (ActionChains(browser).key_down(Keys.CONTROL)
                          .send_keys('t')
                          .key_up(Keys.CONTROL)
                          .perform())
    file_path = html_path / 'file_1.html'
    browser.get('file://' + str(file_path))
```